# How to get the location of a clicked hyperlink?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

Suppose I have a hyperlink residing in cell B4 that will send the user to cell X30. The typical VBA hyperlink-clicking event only gives you access to the hyperlink's "target" (cell X30). But I want to obtain the *location* (cell B4) of the hyperlink, so that the code I run can be dependent on *where* the hyperlink physically is. Is there a way to do this?

One option I've already tried is using the ActiveCell object. Problem is, for each hyperlink I would need to specify its own location *as* the target, because ActiveCell only operates *after* the hyperlink is followed, meaning it refers to the target, not the location. Actually doing this *could* work, since I only use the hyperlink as a macro-initiating button (not as a 'link'), but since I have so many of them and will be copy-pasting them, I would need a way of auto-specifying "target = self" or something (rather than "target = B4").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

    Debug.Print Target.Range.Address

End Sub
```

In your example I put a hyperlink in B4 by right-clicking --> Hyperlink --> Place in this Document --> Sheet1, cell reference X30.

When I click the link the output I get in the immediate window is

`$B$4`

This is the address of where the hyperlink resides.

Additionally, if you're going to be hyperlinking to other sheets and you want to see the 'parent' (or where the hyperlink originated from) sheet name you can use the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

    Debug.Print "'" & Target.Range.Parent.Name & "'!" & Target.Range.Address

End Sub
```

In my quick test I put a hyperlink on Sheet3 that referenced cell A1 on Sheet1 and, when clicked, it returned

`'Sheet3'!$B$2`

Comment: Huh. Could've swore I tried that and it didn't work. But now it works. Doesn't make sense. Anyway thanks for the answer!